# AWS custom TCP port access for ejabberd in ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, tcp, ejabberd

[image]I want to access the custom TCP port on aws ubuntu ejabberd. Eajjb erd installation is perfectly working when accessed via wget on the terminal of the system. But not able to access via the browser. All the access rule for inbound traffic have been set in the aws security group. I'm not able to figure out the problem that why the interface is not avalilable on browser.

```
--2015-10-03 07:02:00--  http://iglimped.com:5280/admin/
```

Resolving iglimped.com (iglimped.com)... 52.74.228.147
Connecting to iglimped.com (iglimped.com)|52.74.228.147|:5280... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are actually putting incorrect login and password credentials on the admin interface.